# RAM usage of very small systems

Tags: full-node, cost-of-node-option

What is the absolute bare minimum RAM required for a full node.  So for example a pi zero with 512MB RAM, could that act as a full node?

If not what components are causing the RAM usage, my own theory is that the txleveldb is fully loaded to RAM?  If so as the chain gets longer, RAM usage will need to increase?

Comment: Theoretically you can have a very small amount of RAM if you have enough swap, but performance will be unacceptable.  Anecdotally, on an amd64 Linux box, bitcoind has an RSS stable at about 650 MB.  You can adjust the sizes of various caches to make that larger or smaller.

Comment: So I tried reducing the dbcache to around 4MB and that has a small effect, but not enough, what other caches are available to be reduced?

Answer (score 1):

just look at the Page where its written Sir

https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#special-cases

2 Gigabyte RAM you must have,  otherwise fail you will ;)

And what i forgot to say, it is not the length of the Blockchain, it is the mass on Data for Transactions, forwarding money, Blocks and so, Mempool simple.